# How to load my images using holder.js bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, svg, holder.js

I am building a product listing page with thumbnails using bootstrap3. And I want to use a thumbnail from Bootstrap which in turn `bootstarp` also using `Holder.js`. I have read documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails) and also [here](https://github.com/imsky/holder).

They all talk about this syntax: after you load js file.

```
<img src="holder.js/200x300">
```

I have tried to inspect and look that where and how the image source are retrieved, since I want to load that using a **foreach in PHP.**

Here my inspection result:

[image: holder js and bootstrap]

So ,as you can see from the image, there is a `data:svg...` something which I didn't understand.

To wrap up my question:

1. How do load images using hodelr.js?
2. Is there conversion needed for all images to be seen on thumbnails view?
3. Where can Hodler.js retrieve images and how could you do it dynamically?

I have the following I didn't see any `svg:generated`:

```
 <div class="thumbnail">
           <img data-src="holder.js/100%x200" alt="100%x200"  class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" src="../assets/images/products/ring.jpg" data-holder-rendered="true" style="height: 200px; width: 100%; display: block;">
           <div class="caption">
            <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks, we fixed this in the docs: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/15426

Answer (score 2):

```
<img src="holder.js/200x300">
```

Holder.js is an image placeholders. It render the code as image.

Change your code to real image as below and set the the sizes.

```
<img src="you image path + image " width="200" height="300">
<img src="images/apple.jpg" width="200" height="300">
```

Comment: i dont really see the diffrence

Comment: Bootstrap is showing here an example of thumbnail listing. Nothing about the place holder. You can add any image inside the thumbnail div tag. Forget about the image holder. Add img tag and test in your browser

Comment: dude i have added the following ...
  <img data-src="holder.js/100%x200" alt="100%x200"  class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" src="../assets/images/products/tshirt.jpg" data-holder-rendered="true" style="height: 200px; width: 100%; display: block;"> ..i see image only no hacks!!

Comment: Please remove data-src="holder.js/100%x200" from the img tag and check

Comment: please see the uipdated question

Comment: if you keep the kolder.js inside the <img> tag. The image will not visible. If you remove that. Then it will work. SVG image file has been created by holder.js.